# Request for an account merge

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

Can I have [a question I asked before joining the site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29430/is-there-a-latex-symbol-for-order/29492) added to the list of questions that shows in [my profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22544/jeff)?

Comment: I edited the title to more accurately reflect your problem.  The new title should attract more mod attention than the last, anyway.

Comment: You beat me to it, actually. I realized I hadn't changed the title and when I tried to edit it, the system wouldn't let me because you were doing it. :D

Comment: Hi Jeff. Follow the steps outlined in the duplicate on the TeX site. Your TeX account that's linked to your master SE account is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10580/jeff) and [this is the account you want to ask the mods to merge into it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8081/jeff).

Comment: You should flag the question for mod attention.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of accounts, an unregistered, cookie-based account, and a registered account.

You have both. One [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8081/jeff) and one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10580/jeff). Note that the first one says "Unregistered" next to the name. Only a moderator can merge them.

Also note that the question you linked to is on the Tex Stack Exchange site, while the *profile* you linked to is on the *Math* Stack Exchange site.  Those accounts are kept separate as well, and this part is intentional.

Comment: What's the point of answering with "you need to wait for somebody else"?

Comment: So then do I have to create (yet) another registered account on Tex Stack Exchange? If so, can that one be merged with my first question? Also, isn't there a master profile which includes all of my accounts? When I came over to this site, it let me use my other userid to log in. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek So he knows what's going on?  Besides, this *does* answer his question of "Can this happen?".

Comment: @Jeff No, you don't need to create another one; you already have plently.  :P  There *is* actually a master account.  Yours is [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/1156012/jeff).